# Unlock iphone 4s

Tags: iphone

My iphone 4s was orignally with orange, latterly with virgin. I'd like to unlock to give it to my granddaughter to use wth o2. I no longer have the original sim. Is this possible ?

I do have a virgin pay-as-you-go sim available if that would help.

Comment: Which country? I guess UK - but then aren't the phones unlocked so just put a new SIM in

Answer (score 1):

Most carriers will unlock the phone if you paid for it for over a year or so and do not have any payments that you owe. You have to call and ask.

This question is more for the orange carrier not really for stack exchange. Contact them and let us know what they said.